# Why doesn't java allow to declare and initialize a class-level variable in two different steps

Tags: java

Can anyone explain me,

1. Why doesn't java allow to declare and initialize a class-level variable in two different steps.
2. Why can't I declare a public variable in public method.

```
public class Class10 {
    public String i=" ";
    public String j;
    j=" "; //Does-Not work

    public void method(String[] args){ 
        public String k=" "; // Does-not work  
        j=" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because those are part of Java's syntactical rules as defined in the [JLS: the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: What would it mean to have a `public` local variable as opposed to a `private` local variable? They are already local.

Comment: You can initialize static member in a static block..

Comment: Let say if it does..then when do you think the variable defined in the method should get initialized? When we load the class load or when we call the method?

Comment: 1) You can, but you need to surround it with `{ }` which will represent initialization block 2) What is the point? What such variable would even represent? If it should be field available from outside of this class (you said it is `public`) then do you really want to create it only when method will be invoked? What should happen if someone would like to access `k` before invoking `method` (methods code wasn't executed so `k` wasn't created yet)? What should happen when someone would want to access `k` but `method` would be invoked more than once (which `k` should be then returned)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It is possible with the right syntax (but discouraged) :

```
public class Class10 {
  public String i=" ";
  public String j;
  {j=" ";} //This is called an "Instance initialization block"
  //It would be better to do it in a constructor.
```

2) It does not make sense :

- If you want it to be visible to others methods, it should be an attribute.
- If you want it to be local to the methods, it should be a variable.

Comment: It is still different from what he wants to realize as well as you did within a block.

Comment: @Cold what do you mean?

Comment: @Arnaud Denoyelle I have an other question. What access modifiers can we give to variables in methods?

Comment: @Cold A variable defined in a method is only visible in the method. Hence, it is not possible to give access modifiers to variables in methods.